# increase the SET Text Size in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am implementing Json From XML in the way it is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815371/Data-Parsing-SQL-to-JSON). 
The Problem was that it increases the Default Text size and it is truncated the results in Json Format. I want the FULL output. How can we increase the Set Text Size from 2147483647 to bigger value but it is not saving and same short string is comes in output.

Comment: Where is the truncation happening?  Is it on the results window in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  If so, you have to go into options and increase the size of the output, and then you have to save your query, close the current query window and open a new one.  The changed output size only applies to new query windows that are opened after you make the change.

Comment: Yes this is in the Query Result Window and when i tried to increse the Text size then it generates an error saying

TEXTSIZE value should be an integer between 0 and 2147483647.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Solution. Here it is.

The Query window is only for display purpose. And it has the option of "Save results As". I just Save the Results as Text file and it saves the Full Result there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the TEXTSIZE controls how much text SQL Server hands back.  There is another setting under "Tools | Options | Query Results | SQL Server | Results to Grid, Results to Text" that lets you control how much of the data returned from SQL Server is displayed in the output window.

It sounds like the truncation is happening when SSMS renders the output, not when SQL Server hands the data to SSMS.  You shouldn't need to change TEXTSIZE, especially since it is already set to 2GB.

After you change these settings under "Tool | Options | ...", you have to open a new query window, since the changed settings only apply to new query windows.